# Yii2: Non-Scenario fields are not saved

Tags: yii2

I'm using different scenario for validation purpose.

The field email is not required in a scenario but if i pass email, it is not getting saved in DB.

Rules in Model:

```
 [['firstname','email'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
```

Scenario function

```
 public function scenarios() {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['insert2'] =  ['firstname', 'status'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

In controller:

```
$model = new User();
$model->scenario = "insert2";
$model->load($data);
print_r($model);
```

Print_r returns email with empty

Comment: Your "insert2" scenario doesn't include the `email` property, so of course it won't be massively assigned. What do you find surprising about this?

Comment: email is not mandatory field on insert2 scenario but if it comes, then it should be inserted. This is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii2, when you want the rule to be applied on certain scenarios, you can specify the on property of a rule, like the following

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [

            //rule applied only in scenario 'insert2'
            [['first_name','status'], 'required','on' => 'insert2'],


            //rule applied  in all scenarios 
            ['email','safe'],

            //rule applied only in scenario 'insert3'
            [['first_name','status','email'], 'required','on' => 'insert3'],       
        ];
    }
```

Now if you specify `$model->scenario = "insert2"` in controller then **first_name and status are required** and email if you give any value will get saved because  `['email','safe']` rule also applied here.

If you specify `$model->scenario = "insert3"` in controller then **first_name,status and email** are now required fields and rule `['email','safe']` also get applied.

Please note you may not use  `public function scenarios() {..` here

From  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#validation-rules

Comment: Thanks.. I did a mistake in rules and fixed. Your answer was helpful to fix that issue.

Answer (score 6):

From [Yii 2 load() docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail):

> Note, that the data being populated is subject to the safety check by setAttributes().

Now, [setAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#setAttributes()-detail) signature:

```
public void setAttributes ( $values, $safeOnly = true )
```

where `$safeOnly` set to `true` means the assignments should only be done to the safe attributes. A safe attribute is one that is associated with a validation rule in the current $scenario.

So `email` must be included in the scenario.

Comment: if i include email in scenario, then email will be required field.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. It will be required only if there is validation rule `required` added for this field.